# VB.Net : collection of wpf windows

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I am quite new to VB.Net.

I am writing a program similar to a survey. WPF windows pop-up with questions one after each other in sequential order. Now, my client asked to randomize order for some of the windows. I thought I can maybe have a collection of windows, and present these windows sequentially in random order. However, I am not finding any information on it.

Can someone show me example how I can store different windows in some sort of collection, and then show them in sequential order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this: *(not tested)*

```
Dim l_windows As New List(Of Window)

' However you want to go about populating your list of windows...
l_windows.Add( new Window1() )
l_windows.Add( new Window2() )

Dim l_random As New Random()
Dim l_randomWindows = From w In l_windows
                      Select Ordinal = l_random.Next(),
                             Window = w
                      Order By Ordinal
                      Select Window

For Each l_window in l_randomWindows
    l_window.Show()
Next
```

Note that the standard .NET randomizer is only pseudo-random, and a poor choice if you need randomness for statistical purposes, etc. (It's not hard to find better random number generators, though.)

Explanation of the LINQ query:

- Iterate through l_windows, assigning each item in the collection to `w`

  ```
  From w In l_windows
  ```
- For each `w`, create a new anonymous object with two properties: assign a random number to `Ordinal` and assign `w` to `Window`. (The compiler will create a class which describes this anonymous type in the background, but you will never need to deal with that directly.)

  ```
  Select Ordinal = l_random.Next(),
         Window = w
  ```
- Order the anonymous typed objects by `Ordinal`. If two `Ordinal`s are the same, then it will simply put one after the other (probably based on the original order of l_window, though I've not tested it).

  ```
  Order By Ordinal
  ```
- For each anonymous typed object in the freshly reordered list, select the object assigned to the Window property. LINQ is smart enough to select the value, rather than to create an anonymous type with a single property.

  ```
  Select Window
  ```
- The `IEnumerable(Of Window)` is then assigned to `l_randomWindows`.

> **Note** that the object represented by IEnumerable is not a collection in and of itself. The compiler will actually create an query object, which is not executed until you actually attempt to retrieve an item from the collection (as in the `For` loop). This query will execute again and again, returning differently ordered results each time (because the `l_random.Next()` will be called each time).
>
> If you want to get a stable collection back, simply call `l_randomWindows.ToList()` or `l_randomWindows.ToArray()` and assign the result to a variable.

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with LINQ. Does the above mean: 
1. select rows of random number and window
2. order these rows by these random numbers
3. select all windows in current order
4. Show all windows.

Can l_random.Next() produce two identical numbers ? What will happen then? thanks.